Markdown pandas dataframe in python
I've noticed that in order to help someone with pandas I spend 5 minutes manually recreating dataframe from the string.
What would be the best approach to convert StackOverflow string table into pandas dataframe in python?
Update:
Thank you very much for linking the relevant answers.
Based on that I've updated my code (hopefully it would help someone in future):
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

table_sting = """|Firm Name|Last Name|First Name|
    |---|---|---|
    |Firm1|A|Adam|
    |Firm2|B|Boris|
    |Firm3|C|Charlie|
    |Firm4|D|David|"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(table_sting.replace(' ', '')),sep='|').dropna(axis=1,how='all').iloc[1:]
print(f"df = pd.DataFrame({df.to_dict('list')})")

md_table  = df.to_markdown(index=False)    
print(md_table)


The text formatting is called Markdown
